# Use of Azure Grid Events to trigger ADF Pipe to move On-premises CSV files to Azure database

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

We have series of CSV files landing every day (daily Delta) then these need to be loaded to Azure database using Azure Data Factory (ADF). We have created a ADF Pipeline which moves data straight from an on-premises folder to an Azure DB table and is working.

Now, we need to make this pipeline executed based on an event, not based on a scheduled time. Which is, based on creation of a specific file on the same local folder. This file is created when the daily delta files landing is completed. Let's call this `SRManifest.csv`.

The question is, how to create a Trigger to start the pipeline when `SRManifest.csv` is created? I have looked into Azure event grid. But it seems, it doesn't work in on-premises folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that you cannot configure an Event Grid trigger to watch local files, since you're not writing to Azure Storage. You'd need to generate your own signal after writing your local file content.

Aside from timer-based triggers, Event-based triggers are tied to Azure Storage, so the only way to use that would be to drop some type of "signal" file in a well-known storage location, after your files are written locally, to trigger your ADF pipeline to run.

Alternatively, you can trigger an ADF pipeline programmatically (.NET and Python SDKs support this; maybe other ones do as well, plus there's a REST API). Again, you'd have to build this, and run your trigger program after your local content has been created. If you don't want to write a program, you can use PowerShell (via `Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline`).

There are other tools/services that integrate with Data Factory as well; I wasn't attempting to provide an exhaustive list.

Comment: I have found Azure Power Automate (Flow) makes this happen. Has anyone tried this? Appreciate if anyone could share some tutorials how to trigger the pipe using Automate. Thanks

Comment: Tool/product/tutorial/etc recommendations are out of scope / off-topic here. With just a quick web search, I can see at least one. Note that this is roughly equivalent to what I stated in my answer - just using a different tool, instead of custom code or PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the *Azure Logic Apps* for File System connector Triggers. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector).